# How to install Zen Coding (now called Emmet) with Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I tried searching on Google but have not found any install instructions. Can someone help me out. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks!

Comment: Just so the answer makes more sense without editing it. "Zen Coding" is now called "Emmet". Here's an insanely useful cheat sheet for it. http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/

Comment: Any chance you can accept my answer? It's been a while.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

[Install the package manager](https://packagecontrol.io/installation), then type <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type "Install", press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type "Emmet" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

Comment: Thank you! But i have not "install package" yet. I'll try get it and do what you said.

Comment: For Window7, can you give me the way you install it? thank you so much!

Comment: Did you restart Sublime Text?

Comment: Yes, i finished with ubuntu and now i'm trying install with window7.

Comment: I'd imagine it's the same thing you did for Ubuntu. I used the same way installing it on OSX.

Comment: Great! I have successfully installed! Thank you very much! Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed the Sublime Text 3.
To enable *Emmet* follow these steps:

1. Open the Sublime Text 3
2. Go to Tool-> Command Palette..
3. Select Install Package by searching "install".
4. Again new window opens type "Emmet" and select first one.
5. That's it new Zen coding( Emmet ) is enable in your Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 3):

A detailed article on 
[How to Install Emmet In Sublime Text 3](http://resource-guru.com/tutorials/install-emmet-sublime-text-3)
and a [video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIOv-yGMa-E) on same

Answer (score 3):

Open Sublime Text 3.
Open console by pressing CTRL + ` or going to View > Show Console.
Paste the following code and press Enter.

```
import urllib.request,os; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); open(os.path.join(ipp, pf), 'wb').write(urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())

*Wait for a minute and restart your Sublime Text.*
```

**Installing Emmet (Main Part)**

- After you have successfully installed Package Control, open Command
  Palette by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + P or going to Tools > Command
  Palette…
     Type install and click on Package Control: Install Package.
     After loading type Emmet in the search bar and click on Emmet.
     Wait for it to install (and yes this is also a step). Leave your system for 2-3 minutes as it will install some required repositories
  also like PyV8. Keep an eye on the Status bar (the light grey bar in
  the bottom of your editor which shows the Line and the Column
  number).

  After your status bar is clean and has nothing except the Line and Column number restart you Sublime.

and Look out..!!! Emmet is installed in your Sublime.